# How to pass dynamic parametrs to query in MS Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I need to build a report in Power BI. I can get the data for the report by calling the MS SQL Server stored procedure with parameters. Question: How can I pass dynamic parameters from a report to a stored procedure call? And the second question: one of the parameters is the user login. How to get it in Power BI and transfer the stored procedure call parameter to?

Comment: If you want to use the user name at run time, look into Row Level Security. It can filter rows based on user, although it's difficult to use it to do anything else (i.e. pick a default selection)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to query editor, and create the required parameters (from manage parameters)
2. Now create a new query that calls SQL procedure, you can pass hardcoded parameters for now.
3. Once data are imported, go to advance editor and replace the hard-coded parameter in the query part with the parameter you created, you will have to concat it.

refer: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-user-parameter-in-power-bi/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are these parameters static? I need dynamic parameters, taken from some input field in my report. Is it possible using the approach you suggested?

Comment: @user1277317 Those inputs are static, if you use Power BI Templates those will be required to be filled in and used for loading the data. But that is exclusive to Power BI Desktop behaviour, not for published reports.